# Gradient descent vs Contrastive Divergence

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

What are the differences (if any) between gradient descent and Contrastive Divergence?

I understand how gradient descent is used to train neural networks via back-propogation, but I've just started learning about Restricted Boltzmann Machines (RBMs) and I keep coming across references to Contrastive Divergence, a concept that I'm not familiar with. This reference here (http://blog.echen.me/2011/07/18/introduction-to-restricted-boltzmann-machines/) suggests that Contrastive Divergence is like an "approximate gradient descent", but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Have a look here - [Notes on Contrastive Divergence](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ojw/files/NotesOnCD.pdf).

Comment: Two connected but different approaches to estimate the hidden parameters. You can write out the formula of Gradient descent and Contrastive Divergence, then the difference is immediately clear.